# How to sort the columns with values greater than equal to 0.2 on a whole?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have data frame like following:

```
df:

Sample  Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type
T1       0       0.289    0.378   0       1      K
T2       0       0.167     0     0.875  0.389    K
T3    0.186     0.12345    0      0     0.187    K
T4   0.11234     0.1789    0     0.457  0.786    L
T5    0.2347     0.2567    0      0       0      L
T6   0.28769       0     0.123   0.1987 0.1565   L
T7    0.142        0     0.1987   0       0      M
T8       0       0.1256  0.123   0.129   0.111   M
T9    0.187      0.987     0     0.237   0.783   M
```

How to sort the column wise with values >=0.2, sorting should not be applied on values <0.2.

I tried in this way. But didn't work

```
sort(apply(df[grepl("Region",length(colnames(df)], 2, function(x) 
 any(x >= 0.2)),decreasing=TRUE)
```

Comment: Haven't you already asked the same question multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop with `lapply` on the 'Region' columns, create  logical vector ('i1'), use that to subset the values, `order` and update it

```
nm1 <- grepl("Region",names(df1))
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[nm1], function(x) {
         i1 <- x >= 0.2 
         x[i1] <- x[i1][order(x[i1], decreasing = TRUE)]
         x})
```

Comment: It should also sort the arrangement of the columns

Comment: @raju Your question seems to be to sort the columns.

Comment: Yes, my mistake I edited now

Comment: @raju the logic for `sort` the arrangement of columns is not clear

Comment: hey Akrun, no I don't need that now. Anyways. Thanks for helping me out